# remove a property from texfield in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code for a HTML form:

```
<input type="text" name="myText" value="Enter Your Name" readonly>
<input type="button" onclick="inn()" value="edit">
```

When I click on the edit button I would like the read only property of the textfield to be removed so that the user can edit the value of the text-field. I do not want to change any other property.

I also do not want to edit the entire form also with:

```
formId.innerHTML=
```

The above code shows only one text-field and one button. On my page there are 12 text-fields and 5 buttons. I would like to remove the property not re-edit the entire property again.

Please suggest some JavaScript code that would help.

```
function inn()
{
   // What do I type here to remove the readonly property of the "MyText" text-field?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get the `<input>` element from DOM. One possible way:

```
var element = document.getElementsByName("myText")[0];
```

Then, to remove `readonly` you can either change the `readOnly` property:

```
element.readOnly = false;
```

or to explicitly remove the attribute:

```
element.removeAttribute("readonly");
```

Comment: ya bro its working . lot of thanks for that bro . u r a really good programer .. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try:

Give an ID to your input element:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" value="Enter your name" readonly />
```

JS

```
function inn() {
    document.getElementById('myText').readonly = false;
}
```

Comment: bro not working . give me any other solution for that . as u suggest me here is my code - http://www.datafilehost.com/download-b5bb3c42.html and its not working

Answer (score 0):

First Assign an ID to your textbox.

i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="myText" id ="txt" value="Enter Your Name" readonly>
<input type="button" onclick="inn()" value="edit">
```

Then you can write in your javascript -

```
function inn() 
{ 
    if ($('#txt').attr("readonly") == true) 
    { 
        $('#txt').val(''); 
        $('#txt').removeAttr("readonly"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The OP did not mention jQuery in the question.

Comment: this one is also not work in my . check this bro . is i made any mistake there - http://www.datafilehost.com/download-34696cc5.html